# CKEDITOR : Programatically close Find Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm creating a new plugin in CKEditor.In this plugin, I want some functionality of Find plugin.

So, I try to trigger it using the below command.

```
editor.execCommand('find');
```

Trying to close it with the below command.

```
if(editor.execCommand('find')){
   $('.cke_dialog_ui_button').click();
  //It will close the dialogBox.
}
```

But I know this is not the right way to do this.

I want to close it automatically in a right way.How can I do this?

Anyone, Please help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {});
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
    editor.on( 'dialogShow', function( evt ) {
        evt.data.definition.dialog.hide();
    });                 
    editor.execCommand('find');
});
```

Please see: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dialog.html#method-hide